# How to add an exception to a deeply nested file in .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

We are trying to ignore a folder and add an exception to a specific file, within that folder, which is nested several levels deep.

Here is how i am doing it right now **(works, but is complicated)**:

```
/ignored_folder/*
!/ignored_folder/foo/
/ignored_folder/foo/*
!/ignored_folder/foo/exception_file.txt
```

Is there a way to simplify this, that would work for any depth? This configuration does not make `exception_file.txt` an ignore exception **(does not work)**:

```
/ignored_folder/*
!/ignored_folder/foo/exception_file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring folders means not looking inside them at all, and `ignored_folder/*` matches folder names inside the (now-misleadingly-named) ignored_folder. You want

```
ignored_folder/**
!ignored_folder/**/
```

That's "recursively ignore all *files* inside `ignored_folder`, but don't skip over nested folders, look in side them anyway because I might want to cherry-pick individual files inside them".

And then after that you can casually add

```
!ignored_folder/foo/exception_file.txt
```

edit: but tttt I'd start with [@TheIceBar's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976199/1290731) and ignore or squelch any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want that exact behavior and do not care about it being an elegant or maintainable solution you can have only `/ignored_folder/*` in your `.giignore` and when you create the `exception_file.txt` you can override the ignore rules with `git add --force /ignored_folder/foo/exception_file.txt`.

Note that you only have to do this once. Once the `exception_file.txt` is tracked it will not be ignored as ignore rules only apply to new files.

However, as I said, this is inelegant but it creates exactly that behavior.