# Git how to ignore all children and only certain grandchildren in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure like this:

```
/accounts/

/accounts/customer1234/

/accounts/customer1234/webhooks/

/accounts/customer1234/uploads/

/accounts/customer1234/junk.txt

/accounts/customer5678/

/accounts/customer5678/webhooks/

/accounts/customer5678/other_file.xml
```

I want to ignore everything except what's in the 'webhooks' directories. This is what I have:

```
# Customer information
accounts/**/*

# Don't ignore the webhooks. 
!accounts/**/webhooks/
!accounts/**/webhooks/*
!accounts/**/webhooks/**/*
!accounts/**/webhooks/**/**/*
!accounts/**/webhooks/**/**/**/*
!accounts/**/webhooks/**/**/**/**/*
```

The problem is that Git is still ignoring the entire /accounts directory and everything inside it. There are many customer account folders and I can't name them all individually. How can I ignore everything but all content in each customer's /webhooks directory?

Git 2.3 is installed on the server. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976259/7976758

Comment: Git 2.3 is pretty old, by the way. Unless it was a typo for 2.30?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was actually that I had a line further up in the .gitignore file that contained this:

```
**/*.log
**/**/*.log
**/**/**/*.log
**/**/**/**/*.log
```

Not very smart, I know. I read the Git documentation more thoroughly. That's the main reason why the files were still being ignored though:

Here are the lines I wound up using to unignore the files I want. I had to specify file types because there were a bunch of images mixed in:

```
# Customer information
accounts/*/**
# Don't ignore the webooks. 
!/accounts/*/webhooks/
!/accounts/*/webhooks/*.php
!/accounts/*/webhooks/*.js
!/accounts/*/webhooks/*.css
!/accounts/*/webhooks/*.html
!/accounts/*/webhooks/**/
!/accounts/*/webhooks/**/*.php
```